# Várias perguntas específicas numa só pergunta sobre o mesmo assunto

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-amplas

Hoje me deparei com essa pergunta: [Como funcionam os ponteiros do C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106227/d%C3%BAvidas-simples-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-ponteiros)

O título me pareceu suspeito de que merecia uma edição para torná-lo mais claro até eu entrar na pergunta e ver que se tratava de várias dúvidas em uma só. Alguém prontamente comentou na pergunta, indicando a(o) autor(a) que lisse a página "Como perguntar".

Eu já ia sugerir a(o) colega que explicasse exatamente qual era o problema para o(a) autor(a), já que a resposta era muito simples: a pergunta era ampla demais. Entrei na página para copiar e colar o trecho que fala sobre isso. Eis o trecho:

> Seja específico
>
> Se você fizer uma pergunta vaga, terá uma resposta vaga. Porém, se
>   você der detalhes e contexto, podemos fornecer uma resposta útil.

A pergunta certamente não é vaga. As dúvidas são bastante claras e específicas, só que são várias. Agora eu é que estou em dúvida: uma pergunta com essas características é bem-vinda?

Comment: É mais recomendável quebrar uma dúvida com muitos questionamentos específicos em varias perguntas isoladas, assim, facilita quem for responder, e também torna tanto as perguntas quanto as respostas mais objetivas.

Comment: Entendo e concordo. Mas em casos como o que apontei, um sinalização de "muito ampla" seria aceitável, dada a forma como o "Como perguntar" define a situação?

Comment: A sinalização é sim adequada, mas pode induzir outros usuários a fecharem a pergunta (e aí ela não poderia ser respondida enquanto não for reaberta). Sinalizando ou não, é sempre recomendado comentar e orientar o usuário (neste caso, linkando para outras perguntas, que já respondem algumas das dúvidas, e a postar as restantes separadamente).

Comment: Certo. Obrigado!